# Clear all drop down lists when parent drop down is set to default value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dropdownlistfor and the following code which works as expected (and a similar chunk for StateId):

```
$('#CountryId').change(function () {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("StateList", "Manage")', {id: $('#CountryId').val()}, function (data) {
            var items = '<option value="">Select a State</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#StateId').html(items);
            $('#CityId').html('<option value="">Select a City2</option>');
        });
    });
```

However, if Country is set to the default value (after having been previously set to something else), the change is not triggered and nothing happens (I understand why..and I don't want/need the state options if that happens too). Therefore, I can wind up with a State and City selected and no Country (not good). What I'm trying to accomplish is when my CountryId drop down list is set to the following:

```
<option value="">Select a Country</option>
```

Then the following should happen:

```
$('#StateId').html('<option value="">Select a State</option>');
$('#CityId').html('<option value="">Select a City</option>');
```

I just don't know how to set the first part regarding CountryId. How would I go about doing that? I messed around with `$('#CountryId').val` and a couple of others with no luck.

Also, it seems that if I take this approach, it will essentially be writing over the default value for State and City if they are already the defaults (e.g. when the user hasn't previously set the values before or in the registration form)? Does that matter? Is there a better way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind `change` event country then on check the value, with use `.val()` to change the drop-down value of `state` and `country`.

```
$("#CountryId").on('click', function () {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#StateId').val('');
        $('#CityId').val('');
    }
});
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('select').val('')
      }, 2000)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Select a State</option>
  <option value="Whatever" selected>Whatever</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. However, your exact code leaves the City and State lists still available for the user to choose again after they've set country to the default value. So, I used your first two lines, then my two lines above for `StateId` and `CityId.`